# Chrome App using sockets api run without opening Chrome window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I want to build a Chrome App to listen notifications sent by my Lab, and I don't want to open a Chrome window(just let the app run in background silently, and pop a box when I have a new message). But sockets api is only for packaged app, and packaged app has no background permission, what should I do? Thx.

Comment: What kind of notifications are you sending? chrome.pushMessaging and chrome.gcm (see https://developer.chrome.com/apps/gcm) receive notifications even if the app is not running.

Comment: Thx Dinh, our Lab doesn't connect to the Internet, so I guess GCM can't help me. Thx again.

Answer (score 0):

(Quick answer, will edit later with more info.)

Chrome Packaged Apps don't need that permission, they have a background page by default.  Most (say, 99% of existing) chrome apps will open a window when they launch, but thats optional.

If your app has an open window, the runtime will keep your application running an not move into an idle state.  However, if you are using certain APIs, such as having an open TCP server socket listening for incoming connections, its very unlikely that the runtime will shut your app down unless the system is under serious constraints.

Comment: Indeed, the app keeps alive when I launch it and keep Chrome open. However, I want it run when system setup, and still run even when I close Chrome window. Thx for reply.

Comment: How are you launching the application?  On which platform?  There is now a chrome app launcher directly integrated with desktop platforms and you should not need Chrome windows open to launch chrome apps.  Starting chrome apps on system startup.. I'm not sure how to do.

Comment: They say they will support, but not now. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=163770

Comment: My own solution is to build an extension with background permission (just an empty extension do nothing, but make sure chrome runs in background all the time), and move the app shortcut to startup folder.